# Regular expression to match exactly the start of a string

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to build a regular expression in c# to check whether a string follow a specific format.

The format i want is: [digit][white space][dot][letters]

For example:

**123 .abc** follow the format

**12345 .def** follow the format

**123 abc** does not follow the format

I write this expression but it not works completelly well

```
Regex.IsMatch(exampleString, @"^\d+ .")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`^` matches the start of the string, and you got it right.

`\d+` matches one or more digits, and you got that one right as well.

A space in a regex matches a literal space, so that works too!

However, a `.` is a wildcard and will match any one character. You will need to escape it with a backslash like this if you want to match a literal period: `\.`.

To match letters now, you can use `[a-z]+` right after the period.

```
@"^\d+ \.[a-z]+"
```

Answer (score 2):

The [dot is a special character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) in regex, which matches any character (except, typically, newlines). To match a literal `.`, you need to escape it:

```
Regex.IsMatch(exampleString, @"^\d+ \.")
```

If you want to include the condition for the succeeding letters, use:

```
Regex.IsMatch(exampleString, @"^\d+ \.[A-Za-z]+$")
```

Answer (score 0):

For you to get yours to match, keep in mind that the period in regular expressions is a special character that will match any character, so you'll need to escape that.

In addition, \s is a match for any white-space character (tabs, line breaks).

```
^\d+\s+ \..+
```

(untested)